# What does "waffles and unicorns" mean?

Tags: support, unicorns

I cannot call myself new to Stack Overflow (or to the world!), yet I don't understand the meaning of the phrase "**waffles and unicorns**". I have read it on Meta plenty of times, but I didn't figure out what it meant.

Comment: [Waffles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19480/310230) & [Unicorns](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/310230) :)

Comment: [What is up with the waffle fetish?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19392/what-is-up-with-the-waffle-fetish) and [My God—it's full of unicorns!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-god-its-full-of-unicorns)

Comment: Waffles taste good, unicorns taste better *runs away*

Comment: [The many memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)

Comment: This question needs [meta-tag:waffles] and [meta-tag:unicorns] tags, to help future readers find it!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19480#19480) as well as [unicorns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19479#19479) are part of the so called [Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta).

Memes are defined as (taken from said "Memes of Meta"-question):

> Catchphrases and concepts that spread from person to person are known as [memes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_meme), which, courtesy the Internet, can now explode across the Earth like a highly contagious virus (hence "going viral"). As with their real-life counterparts, some infectious diseases are global (pandemic), while others are endemic to specific regions.

Another very well known meme, that also happens to be used daily here on MSO is the [Freehand Circles meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/310230). I.e. comments below a question that includes pictures often complain about the "lack of freehand-drawn circles".

Comment: I can't upvote this because there's no freehand circle.

Comment: @Lucas I don't give a f...inest amount of care about freehand circles! Upvoted!

Comment: The problem with memes is that once people don't know them anymore they kind of stop being memes.

Comment: That link doesn't explain what the waffle meme *is*.  Apparently there was once a discussion of waffles (as food), and now any use of the word "waffle" is funny?  Surely there has to be more to it than that, like some description of how it gets used.  Most of the "explanation" reads more like an in-joke written for people who already know what it's about.  I still have very little idea of why it's funny or could appear in a phrase like the OP mentioned.  A keyboard-shaped waffle iron is pretty cool, but this barely answer the question of what the meme is about.

Answer (score 20):

[image: freehand circle]

Comment: That's a pretty unicorn you've got there!

Comment: I am tempted to start a new meta question: "What does shaky red circle mean?"

Comment: My waffle is *this* big.

Comment: Gush my OCD hurts, please connect the line perfectly.

Comment: -1. Circles are closed figures. That's just a line.

Comment: @jpmc26: -1. Lines don't have ends.  That's just a line segment.

Comment: @Enzokie if you have OCD don't [look at this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: @Will don't be cruel.